# Is there any lock mechanism in Azure Redis Cache while updating an item?

Tags: azure, caching, redis, stackexchange.redis, azure-redis-cache

I'm working on Azure Redis Cache with Azure Search but I couldn't find any clear description about concurrency of Redis Cache.

Here is the case. While overwriting an existing cache item, is it possible to read the item at the same exact time? If yes how does Redis Cache manage this ? Does it lock the item until it gets available or does it give an old version of the item ?

By the way I'm using StackExchange.Redis client.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Redis is single threaded so all operations are atomic. If there is an update/delete there is nobody else that can read that key until the operation finishes. More details here - [single-threaded-nature-of-redis](https://redis.io/docs/management/optimization/latency/#single-threaded-nature-of-redis)

Comment: As I understand from your answer, there is a locking mechanism. Redis Cache waits the get request till the update finishes. So should I use StringGetAsync or StringGet to be able to wait for updating ?

Comment: They both do the same operation against Redis, the async version returns to your code before getting the answer whereas the other makes it wait for it.

Comment: There is only one thread in Redis that serves the incoming requests, so it can't serve 2 concurrent requests. So it doesn't need any locking mechanism. Using StringGetAsync or StringGet has no effect on Redis side, just your client will be blocked by waiting the response or not in the async method.

Comment: Without locking - possible situation, whan valueFactory at client side called multiple times