# Is synchronization required at code level while inserting or removing values from Azure Redis Cache?

Tags: c#, caching, redis, locking, azure-redis-cache

I am using the following singleton class to get / set / remove values from Azure Redis Cache for one of my personal development works.

```
using StackExchange.Redis;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

namespace PoC
{
    public sealed class CacheManager
    {
        public static object mutex = new object();

        public static string EndPoint { get; set; }
        public static string Password { get; set; }
        public static bool UseSsl { get; set; }
        public static int ConnectRetry { get; set; }
        public static int KeepAlive { get; set; }
        public static int ConnectTimeout { get; set; }

        private static ConfigurationOptions ConfigurationOptions;

        private static readonly CacheManager instance = new CacheManager();

        // Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler
        // not to mark type as beforefieldinit
        static CacheManager() { }

        private CacheManager()
        {
            ConfigurationOptions = new ConfigurationOptions
            {
                Password = Password,
                Ssl = UseSsl,
                AbortOnConnectFail = false,
                ConnectRetry = ConnectRetry,
                KeepAlive = KeepAlive,
                ConnectTimeout = ConnectTimeout
            };
        }

        public static CacheManager Instance { get { return instance; } }

        public static string ConnectionString { get; set; }

        Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> lazyConnection = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() =>
        {
            return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(ConfigurationOptions);
        });

        IDatabase Database => lazyConnection.Value.GetDatabase();


        public void Set<T>(string key, T value)
        {
            lock (mutex)
            {
                Database.StringSet(key, ToByteArray(value));
            }
        }

        public T Get<T>(string key)
        {
            T result = FromByteArray<T>(Database.StringGet(key));
            return result;
        }

        public bool Remove(string key)
        {
            lock (mutex)
            {
                var removed = Database.KeyDelete(key);
                return removed;
            }
        }

        public byte[] ToByteArray<T>(T obj)
        {
            if (obj == null)
                return null;
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }

        public T FromByteArray<T>(byte[] data)
        {
            if (data == null)
                return default(T);
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data))
            {
                object obj = bf.Deserialize(ms);
                return (T)obj;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here, I had used lock while inserting values into the database or removing values from the database. But from the following post I came to know that Redis is a single threaded database and all the operations are atomic -

[Is there any lock mechanism in Azure Redis Cache while updating an item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32437237/is-there-any-lock-mechanism-in-azure-redis-cache-while-updating-an-item)

So I believe that the lock I have used is unnecessary and may lead to some performance issues. Please correct me if I am wrong. I am setting the variables (EndPoint, Password etc.) once in the `Application_Start` event. Would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can learn how to use `WATCH` in Redis. https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Transactions.html

```
WATCH key  
isFieldExists = HEXISTS key, field  
if isFieldExists is 1  
MULTI  
HSET key, field, value  
EXEC  
else  
UNWATCH  
return isFieldExists
```

*Example:*

```
var newId = CreateNewId();
var tran = db.CreateTransaction();
tran.AddCondition(Condition.HashNotExists(custKey, "UniqueID"));
tran.HashSetAsync(custKey, "UniqueID", newId);
bool committed = tran.Execute();
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. However, should we apply transactions during insert / remove operations? This contradict what is said here -
https://redis.io/topics/latency#single-threaded-nature-of-redis.
Do we still need to use lock / transactions?

Comment: I mean, you don't need to use lock, just use `WATCH` to commit the transaction.

Comment: Thanks Jason. How should I do this in the code sample I posted above. Do I need to make any change in that code to make it work perfectly (after removing lock)? Please suggest.